# Opencl Segmentation fault while accessing device info

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I'm a newbie in OpenCL programming.
My very first program is giving me a hard time. I wanted to query device name and vendor name of every device in each platform. My system has two platforms, the first one is AMD platform and the second is NVIDIA CUDA platform. I've written the following code to get the desired info.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    try {
            vector<cl::Platform>platforms;
            cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

            cl_context_properties properties[] = {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])(), 0}; 
            cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, properties);

            vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

            string dName(devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>());
            string vendor(devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>());

            cout<<"\tDevice Name:"<<dName<<endl;
            cout<<"\tDevice Vendor: "<<vendor<<endl;    
    }catch(cl::Error  err) {
            cerr<<err.what()<<" error: "<<printErrorString(err.err())<<endl;

            return 0;
    }
```

}

when I change the platform index to 1 in

```
    cl_context_properties properties[] = {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])(), 0};
```

my program crashes with 'Segmentation fault'.

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the size of the platforms vector? I mean how do you know that you have the two platforms properly installed?

Comment: @CaptainObvious Yes I know the size of installed platforms.

Comment: @CaptainObvious. the 'platforms' vector is populated by                   cl::Platform::get(&platforms); and platforms.size() gives me the number of platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using the cl.hpp header file from the AMD APP SDK?  If that is the case then the problem is that the header file calls an OpenCL 1.2 function (can't remember which one) that is supplied by the AMD devices in your system but not by the Nvidia GPU.  Your Nvidia GPU only supports OpenCL 1.1.  The best solution I know is to use the header files for OpenCL 1.1 from the Khronos website.

Comment: I can't change the configuration of the machine to use the header file you mentioned. Is there any flag the I can set in my program? For instance, I included #define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS to enable CL exceptions. Likewise, is there anything like CL_VERSION_1_1?

Comment: Surely you can download the Khronos OpenCL header files to your home folder.  Thereafter, tell the compiler to look in that folder for header files (-I on GCC).  Doing that does not affect any other users or software.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I suggest using the 1.1 C++ header. There was a problem talking to 1.1 devices with the 1.2 C++ header (although I believe it might be fixed in the latest AMD SDK).